# WebView is zoomedIn on some Android devices

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview, android-animation

I am loading SVG animations in the android WebView using Java.
My WebView code in XML is:

```
        <WebView
        android:id="@+id/animationView"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="135dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"/>
```

To load SVG:

```
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webView.clearCache(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        webView.setInitialScale(1);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);

        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/xyz.svg");
        webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

This is working fine. It is fitting SVG in the web view by zooming out.
But sometimes, it is loading SVG by doing too much Zoom In. Sometimes SVG is too much zoomed, unable to resolve it.
This issue is happening once within 10 attempts.